# Combinatorics (2.6.11)

Tags: combinatorics

> Residents of a condominium have an automatic garage door opener that has a row of eight buttons. Each garage door has been programmed to respond to a particular set of buttons being pushed. If the condominium houses 250 families, can resident be assured that no two garage doors will open on the same signal? If so, how many additional families can be added before the eight-button code becomes inadequate? (*Note:* The order in which the buttons are pushed is irrelevant.)

*Solution*
Each of the eight buttons has two possible states: pressed **or** not pressed.
There are $2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 2^8 = 256$ possible states. However, the state where no buttons are pressed has no real-world application. There are only $255$ possible states available to residents, which is 5 more than the number of families the condos can house.

Comment: What is your question?  Without some information on how the codes are assigned, nobody can be assured that they have a unique code.

Comment: That's actually what I'm trying to interpret from the textbook (written verbatim). I think that a code involves pressing between 1 and 8 buttons. For example, one resident may have a code that involves "press 3rd button" to open the garage. Another resident may have the code that involves "press all 8 buttons" to open the garage. They state that order does not matter, otherwise I think it would be                                  8nPr8 + 8nPr7 + 8nPr6 + …+ 8nPr2 + 8nPr1                                                           Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Your solution is correct given your reading of the problem.  The difficulty is that one person might have $3$ as a code while another has $34$ as a code.  If the one with $34$ presses $3$ first the other door will open unless there is an open button that needs to be pressed after you enter a code.

Comment: I agree that there would have to be an open button, and I'd have a lawyer on speed dial when somebody randomly opened my garage door and emptied it out. It's from _Mathematical Statistics_ by Larsen and Marx (5th ed.) and they have some pretty weird problems. Thanks for checking it though.